# textbox not showing decimal points

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a textbox that accepts only two integers and two decimals (like 78.23). But textbox is not showing decimals  when key press on the webpage.allows only two decimal points(40.02)and after point allows only two digits,while entering the number if user point(.)

```
    var upfront = $(parentRow).find("input[name$='upfront-value']")//.removeClass("number-02");
    $(upfront).unbind('keypress');
    $(upfront).removeClass("number2-02");
    $(upfront).removeClass("numberonly");
    $(upfront).addClass("number2-02");          
    $(upfront).removeAttr('maxLength');
    $(upfront).val("");
```

Comment: Don't bother use the [autoNumeric plugin](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/).

Comment: no, i am using in main project..already i used more plugins in projects..can anyone help me for jquery code\

Answer (score 0):

You can define in your input tag in HTML like this:

```
<input name="something" class="something" step="0.01" size="10" id="something" type="number">
```

Use `step` and `size` attributes.

Comment: if i placed type="number",decimal values are not accepted

Comment: Let me ask you.. Are you using `step` attribute as I post it?

Comment: yse,i am trying by using step,size  attributes

Comment: at least can you  please tell me,  required pattern (or) regex for accepting only 89.78 like wise

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery plugin it will help you.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.0/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js

"99.99" This string represents the format that you want.

```
<input type='text' id='num'>
$("#num").mask("99.99");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it. i think this is helpful for you. it is only Allow Two digit value
When TextBox if focusout not take 1 digit value and show error message

```
$( function() {
    $('.two-digits').focusout(function(){
       var v=$(this).val();
        if(v.length >1){

            console.log(v.length);
            $("#show_error").hide();
        }else{
          $(this).val("");
            $("#show_error").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Html code:

```
<input type="text" name="one" class="two-digits"><br>
    <p id="show_error">Only Two Digit Value Allow</p>
```

[**Click to Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Wqn/869/)

Comment: at least can you  please tell me,  required pattern (or) regex for accepting only 89.78 like wise

Comment: i think this is helpful for you.use this Code .. http://jsfiddle.net/9U2Mw/5/   OR http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/57CpM/